# ListView Animation, Animating Childs

Tags: android, listview, animation

I have a implementation of ListView, Problem in hand is animating childs, upon removal of certain elements from listview. To elaborate further, User can select any number of view from list, and can perform multiple delete, upon delete two things has to be done.

1. All those selected item should disappear/delete away from list(Done)
2. Once items are deleted, all the remaining view should animate themselves upward toward list filling all the void places.

Animation is again broken down in two sequences.

1. Delete child should scale down and subsequently fade away (Done)
2. Remaining Item should animate themselves updward filling void places (NEED HELP).

Any help/pointer will be appriciated.

Regards,
techfist

Answer (score 0):

use android:animateLayoutChanges attribute for ListView. see below example

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true" >
</ListView>
```

Comment: This wont help, suppose if am selecting first and third view, its not animating second child to top and subsequently fourth after that and so on. Infact its justing bringing a new view to all the empty position, leaving rest it is.